# Problem with caching, W3TC

Tags: cache

Am using W3TC from a long time but from past few weeks am stuck, as I can't see my edits working. It was all fine in past but from a week my edits in style.css reflects back in like an hour after.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Kckm.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLXOB.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDgZu.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4iDB.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eAGp.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIxct.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMZPU.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9F3h.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWYZq.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way I can think of is to add a unique string to the end of the stylesheet include to get everything to update.

For example, if you are including it in the header.php file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_uri(); ?><?php echo '?v='. time(); ?>" />
```

Of course that will keep it from being cached... ever. So you might want to turn it off and on. You could add a variable to activate it or you could tie it to wp_debug:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_uri(); ?><?php if ( defined('WP_DEBUG') && ! WP_DEBUG ) echo '?v='. time(); ?>" />
```

Or just comment it out when you are done:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_uri(); ?><?php #echo '?v='. time(); ?>" />
```

You can use all of those if you are enqueueing the styles as well.

Comment: I would be doing this as a last resort, Jake. What I was looking for is an answer if I have done some wrong settings in W3TC, thats why I attached those screenshots.